# How to check if user who open webpage has JWT token? Using JS and AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a webpage, hosted locally. When I type in localhost:1111, my page should check if I have a JWT token in the "Request" (I believe) and if I do, display it, if not redirect me to a login page that will handle getting the JWT.

Right now it always redirects me to the login page. Even after I login, it opens my page and then automatically redirects to the login page again. I believe I need to use AJAX to listen for requests for my page and handle the request there.

This is the code i have so far

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    if (this.response == null)
    {
        window.location.href = "LOGIN-PAGE.COM";
    }
    else
    {
        var responseObject = JSON.parse(this.response);

        if (responseObject.token) 
        {
            document.getElementById("userDetails").innerHTML = responseObject.token;
        } 
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("userDetails").innerHTML = "No token received";
        }
    }

} )
```

And it obviously doesn't work. Im new to web stuff but I have some experience with JS.

Comment: what is this.response?

Comment: @mIts really nothing, at this point the code is just pseudo code. Thats basically the work flow Id like achieve. Open my page, i check if ur have a token in the body, if u do, i will display it, if not, I will redirect u to a login page